# Searching an array return dimension where criteria is

Tags: php, arrays, search

Looking to search an array with lots of information I have tried implementing a few ideas from PHP.net's manuals however, I'm, failing.

My objective is to search an array for a given value, if the value is found, i need to get all information that is relevant to it. See array examples and php code.

So for RoomCode 117 = PropertyId in the array
and I would like to grab all for that property

PHP:

```
    $RoomCode = 117
    echo in_array($RoomCode, $_SESSION['PROPERTY_ARR']);
```

ARRAY:

```
Array
(
    [Property One] => Array
        (
            [Property] => Bolt Hole
            [PropertyId] => 117
            [LocationId] => 9

    )
    [Property Two] => Array
        (
            [Property] => Ledge
            [PropertyId] => 1197
            [LocationId] => 10
    )
```

)

My array contains a lot more information for each 'property'. Anymore information, just ask.

Thanks C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$RoomCode = 117;                                                                                                                                                           
$foundProperties = array_filter($_SESSION['PROPERTY_ARR'], create_function('$r', 'return $r["PropertyId"] == '.$RoomCode.';'));
```

Comment: @Russell - Thanks. I've removed unnecessary ).

Answer (score 1):

If you already tested the solutions in the comments to search multidimensional arrays in the PHP documentation for array_search (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and in_array (http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), maybe you should think of a better formating for your array.
Tell me if I'm wrong, but it look like PropertyId is a UNIQUE identifier for each property. It'll be easier and quicker to search an array id if this array is indexed by the property id.
If I modify your sample array, you'll have something like this :

```
Array
(
    [117] => Array
        (
            [Property] => Bolt Hole
            [LocationId] => 9

    )
    [1197] => Array
        (
            [Property] => Ledge
            [LocationId] => 10
    )
)
```

Then, you don't need to search it, if you want the property 117, you just use :

```
$_SESSION['PROPERTY_ARR'][117]
```

Answer (score 0):

i tries my best and simplest solution, please have a look

```
$arr_prop =array
(
    'Property One' => array
    (
            'Property' => 'Bolt Hole',
            'PropertyId' => 117,
            'LocationId' => 9

    ),
    'Property Two' => array
        (
            'Property' => 'Ledge',
            'PropertyId' => 1197,
            'LocationId' => 10
    )
);
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($arr_prop);
$r =117;
$output=array();
foreach($arr_prop as $key=>$value) 
{
    //echo "<pre>";
    //var_dump($value);
    if(is_array($value)) 
    {
        //echo __LINE__;
        if(in_array($r,$value))
            $output = $value;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
```